# N+1 eager loading in Laravel 8.x Blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am using eager loading for my blog comments and replies. If the blog comment `parent_id` is null, I don't have any problems with N+1. However, the moment I assign a comment to a `parent_id` to create a nest of replies, it causes the N+1 problem.

I've tried looking into this issue, and it seems to be coming from the `posts.comments.blade` & `posts.comments-child.blade`, but I cannot figure out why. Any help is appreciated.

**PostComment Model**

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function replies()
{
    return $this->hasMany($this, 'parent_id');
}
```

**PostController**

```
$postComments = PostComment::where([
    'post_id' => $post->id,
    'parent_id' => null
])->with('user', 'replies')->get();
```

**main.blade**

```
@include('posts.comments', ['comments' => $postComments])
```

**posts.comments.blade** & **posts.comments-child.blade**

```
@foreach ($comments as $comment)
    <h6>{{ $comment->user->name }}</h6>
    <p>{{ $comment->comment }}</p>
    <ul>
        @include('posts.comments-child', ['comments' => $comment->replies])
    </ul>
    <hr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Your N+1 issue is coming from `<h6>{{ $comment->user->name }}</h6>` of the replies

Better eager load those too

```
$postComments = PostComment::where([
    'post_id' => $post->id,
    'parent_id' => null
])->with('user', 'replies.user')->get();
```

You will still have the issue if the replies has more replies and so on.